# Efficiently finding shape over multiple rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is about efficiently finding "2D shapes"  in a pandas dataframe. We have a frame generated like this:

```
l = ['>','<','v','^']

def gendf(r,c): 
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(l,size=(r,c)),columns=[i for i in range(c)])
```

I'm looking for the following shape:

```
    ^
<   ?   >
    v
```

With "?" being any character. I have a very ineffective nested loop which does the job, slowly:

```
def co(df):
    c=[]
    for i in list(df.index)[:-2]:
        for j in list(df.columns)[1:-1]:
            if df.loc[i,j]=='^':
                if df.loc[i+2,j]=='v' and df.loc[i+1,j-1]=='<' and df.loc[i+1,j+1]=='>':
                    c.append((i,j))
    return c
```

It just looks for the "top" and checks for the rest when it finds it. As a nested loop, it's very slow - any functions allow me to do this more efficiently?

EDIT: timers for the methods given

```
%timeit co(df)
8.08 s ± 260 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit x1(df) #Chris A's method
1.89 s ± 102 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit x2(df) #sampers' method
6.22 s ± 289 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Let me know if there's an even better way - this already helps a lot!

Comment: Einsenberg you need all positions of this shapes in df?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you could try [`numpy.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) with multiple boolean conditions using [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
# setup
np.random.seed(0)
df = gendf(100, 100)

cond1 = df.eq('<').shift(axis=1)
cond2 = df.eq('>').shift(-1, axis=1)
cond3 = df.eq('^').shift()
cond4 = df.eq('v').shift(-1)

coords = np.argwhere((cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4).to_numpy())
```

[out]

```
[[ 1  1]
 [ 3 85]
 [11 16]
 [14 87]
 [22 92]
 [24 25]
 [25 14]
 [26 38]
 [27 69]
 [27 85]
 [32 54]
 [36 61]
 [39 29]
 ...
 [69 82]
 [70 76]
 [76 41]
 [79 81]
 [81 60]
 [82 13]
 [83 83]
 [87 12]
 [89 16]
 [94  5]
 [94 69]
 [98 16]]
```

Comment: I didn't properly test this... it doesn't seem to work for me, though. I get a far larger set of coords, which don't fit.

Comment: re-accepted... np.nan was returning True so I modified your answer to `coords = np.argwhere((cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4).fillna(False).to_numpy())`

Answer (score 1):

Casting everything to a list is computationally heavy. Using iat for getting 1 element is also faster than loc.

As you requested the fasted solution, although it might not be the cleanest solution:

```
def search(df):
    result = []
    for i in range(z.shape[0] - 2):
        for j in range(1, z.shape[1] - 1):
            if z.iat[i,j] == '^' and z.iat[i+2, j]=='v' and z.iat[i+1 ,j-1]=='<' and z.iat[i+1, j+1]=='>':
                result.append((i+1,j))
    return result
```

timing it versus the other solution:

```
%timeit other_solution(df)
2.67 s ± 152 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit search(df)
12.4 ms ± 836 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```